# PHP Word работа с таблицей

Tags: php, php7

Подскажите как при работа с PHP Word заполнить таблицу, а именно к примеру у нас есть таблица с 1-ой строкой, нам необходимо прочитать данные из бд циклом и к примеру внести 5 строк заполнив их содержимым бд

Comment: В официальной документации разве нет примеров?

Comment: вроде как такого примера нет

Comment: А это тогда что? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_09_Tables.php

Comment: Насколько я правильно понял код, в нем указана создание таблицы. А как я выше описал, необходимо вставить в уже имеющуюся таблицу и при необходимости добавить строки

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что можно дописывать в имеющийся документа ворда через PHPWord, но возможно я неправ.

Comment: К сожалению в том то и проблема, так как по заданию необходимо именно дописывать уже имеющийся документ